# EntityObjectDatasource and where clause on Enum type field

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an `Entity` in my model which has an `Enumeration` type property.

I'm binding a `Gridview` with an `EntityDataSource` to it. By now, everything is fine.

But how can I specify a `WHERE` clause on a `MyEntity.MyEnumProperty`?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Convert.ToInt32(it.MyEnumProperty) = @MyParam // Does not work
CONVERT(it.MyEnumProperty AS INT) = @MyParam // Still does not work
```

I also tried to set `Int32` to `DbType` of my `params` for both these values but it fails. Also, I tried to bind it to a control or specifying a default value but it always fails saying it's impossible to convert a `String` value to `MyEnum`.

I know it may be pretty simple but all my research on Google returned no answer about this.

Comment: Thanks Sammitch. I'm from Quebec so I usualy talk french and my English sometimes sounds realy bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple finaly.

Easiest way were to specify manualy my where clause and convert it. I'd found this answer somewhere saying it's impossible. It wasn't, but only in previous version but work perfectly with EF4.

Here is my where clause :

```
<asp:EntityDataSource [...]
    Where="CAST(it.MyEnumProperty AS System.Int32) = @MyParamInWhereClauseWith">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="MyEnumProperty" DbType="Int32" DefaultValue="1" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```